# interacting with Daemon Files (JAXL)

Tags: php, javascript, command-line-interface, daemon

I am in the process of learning JAXL to interact with my XMPP server. JAXL creates Daemon files to send & receive data to the XMPP server. This is the first time I have worked with any sort of Daemon files and I am getting completely lost in the process.

I am able to initialize and run the daemon through CLI but I don't know what to do next and I can't find any documentation (for JAXL) on how to do so (I've been looking for about 5 hours now).

Any help on the two questions below would be greatly appreciated!

**1. How do I use PHP to interact with a command-line Daemon to Send and Receive Data.**

**2. How would I go about using Javascript to poll a Command-line Daemon to return data?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JAXL library provides two IPC interfaces for interacting with your xmpp client/component daemons:

1. Unix socket domain - JAXL daemons by default support this. You only need to enable them while starting the main loop. See [examples/echo_bot.php](https://github.com/abhinavsingh/JAXL/blob/v3.x/examples/echo_bot.php#L143), towards the end it starts main loop using `'--with-unix-sock' => true`. Once you have done this, you can remotely hook into these background daemons, see [debugging running instance](http://jaxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/users/jaxlctl.html#debug-running-instances) documentation for more detail.
2. Pipes - Another option you have is to use pipes to communicate with background daemons. See [examples/pipes.php](https://github.com/abhinavsingh/JAXL/blob/v3.x/examples/pipes.php) for more detail. You will need to code the required logic yourself into your application files.

For using JAXL daemon via javascript, there are a number of ways of doing this. A few client oriented approaches are as follows:

1. JAXL v3.x have support for BOSH and you can find a working [examples/http_bind.php](https://github.com/abhinavsingh/JAXL/blob/v3.x/examples/http_bind.php). The example is not complete and use it at your own risk (you have been warned). Nevertheless, you can take the idea forward for your application development, combine this example with JAXL HTTP protocol support to push data to your javascript clients. You can even modify this example to work in [JAXL v2.x BOSH style](https://github.com/abhinavsingh/JAXL/blob/master/app/boshchat.php).
2. A stable option is to extend [examples/xmpp_rest.php](https://github.com/abhinavsingh/JAXL/blob/v3.x/examples/xmpp_rest.php). This example demonstrates how to expose a REST interface for your XMPP daemons.